# Android Sucessfuly post on timeline but Post is not shown on facebook timeline

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have made an application on developer.facebooks site. I have got an app ID and made Hashkey and also set it (for debugging keystore as well as signed keystore).

When I login, I am not able to post or share any text.  There is no error message displayed. But if I use another existing apps "app-id" and do same stuff then it shares or posts text successfully :(

Please help

```
facebook.publishMessage(Sharetext);
```

[my code is similar to this](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Simple-Social-Sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You may not submitted the actions for the approval yet.

Check the story in the Activity log in your timeline. Or Follow this url: https://www.facebook.com/me/activity/RESPONSE_ID

Once approved, the stories will appear in the news feed.